# Connect my website to database

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, cpanel

I just purchased my linux server, and domain on godaddy, but now after i uploaded my files to the file manager. I do not know how to make my "init.php" file connect to the database of that cpanel.

```
$db->$mysqli_connect('should this be localhost?','what user name?','passwordhere','databasehere');
```

Comment: Who knows... is your MySQL server running on localhost?  If so, then that should be localhost.  As far as username and password... well, it's whatever username and password is set up on your MySQL server.  And the database?  How could we know what  you named your database...

Comment: its the first time im doing this, and i dont see much this showing what to do. The settings I have is from my xampp mysql. I wanna know if its the same thing for the web server

Comment: Why would it be?  They're two different MySQL servers.  *You* choose your username/password/database name... it's whatever *you* set them up to be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just learned about this recently actually. I will give you an example from what I have compiled for the site I am making. It works for me on linux and should work for you. You must also make sure to make a databse. If you have a web manager you can do it or you could do it through SSH. There are a few steps before what you are also trying to accomplish and if you need help with that you can ask me if you have not finished them already.

So first you have to I guess fill in the variables. You give these 'variables' a value. So lets say this is databaseconfig.php

```
 <?php
define("HOST", "localhost");     // The host you want to connect to.
define("USER", "usernamefordatabse");    // The database username.
define("PASSWORD", "usernamepassword");    // The database password.
define("DATABASE", "databasename");    // The database name.

define("CAN_REGISTER", "any");
define("DEFAULT_ROLE", "member");

define("SECURE", FALSE);  
?>
```

I have this in one file. So I am making each of those variables aka PASSWORD, DATABSE, etc.. mean something. What they now mean is the info to connect to your database.

in another file in have this databaseconnection.php

```
<?php
include_once 'databaseconfig.php';   // As functions.php is not included
$mysqli = new mysqli(HOST, USER, PASSWORD, DATABASE);
?>
```

I use the to connect to the database. Those are two different php files I made for that and I am unsure if you can combine them.

So now say in your main page your index.html or wherever your page is located that wants to connect into the database. On top of that page you have to connect it

```
<?php
include_once 'includes/databasebconnection.php';
?>
```

this goes on top of the page that needs to access the database. That databaseconnection is already connected to the configuration file for your database, databaseconfig,  which is the first set of code. That is an incomplete line up there. I have another one connected that actually runs everything so depending on the results, they get different feedback.

Answer (score 2):

To create databases

Log in to your GoDaddy account.

Click Web Hosting.

Next to the hosting account you want to use, click Manage.

In the Databases section of the Hosting Control Panel, click the icon corresponding to the database you want to create.

Click Add.

Complete the fields. To allow direct access, click Additional Options.

More information [click here](https://in.godaddy.com/help/create-mysql-or-ms-sql-databases-36)